# Flowing text with minimum column width around floated image

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like a way to prevent columns of flowing text from becoming too narrow. For example, in a column of HTML text, there is an image floated to the left. Text flows down the right-hand side of the column around the image, as expected:

[image: Text flowing past an image - kapai!]

However, if the image is almost as wide as the column, then the text ends up being very narrow:

[image: Text flowing narrowly past an image - stink!]

In this case I want the text to simply *not* flow past the image, but to drop below it as if the image were a block:

[image: Text dropping below an image - chur!]

I am trying to find a simple and general way of doing this. It's for a blog - I want to be able to add the image and text, maybe add a class or paste in a bit of markup (sigh), and have the flow work. I would prefer to do it with CSS and HTML only because it's hard to insert JavaScript to the blog posts. I have a couple of methods (see my answers) but neither is satisfactory. Can you do better?

Comment: If you have a solution, then (1) what is it? and (2) why is it not satisfactory?

Comment: Sorry, I am adding my answers even as we speak.

Answer (score 8):

When you set [`display: inline-block;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to an element, the element will be flowed with surrounding content.

So you would need to add a line-break `<br>` to produce a line break in text, but the vertical space of the line will remains as [you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378962/1725764). *[and one more thing happens is the horizontal scroll-bar which will appear [if you decrease the width of the panel](http://jsbin.com/eGug/6/edit).]*

### Introduction

Using `<table></table>` element has a lot of benefits here.

When you use `<table>` element *(as the following)*, it causes the content goes to the next line. And when the remain horizontal space gets lower than width of the `<table>`, it'll go to the next line and push the content down.

And also, horizontally scroll-bar won't appear in this case, because browsers won't display the `<table>` when it hasn't any element inside or any specific `height` or `border` properties.

*(different browsers have different behavior, Mozilla Firefox doesn't display `table` element with a specific `border` property but Google Chrome does.)*

**HTML:**

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" alt="">
<table></table>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
```

**CSS:**

```html
img { float: left; }
table { width: 12em; }
```

Here is the **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/eGug/9/edit)**.

### The Solution

As a pure CSS way, I used [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-element to create a element which behaves like the `<table>` HTML element.

**HTML:**

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
  <p class="content">
    <!-- Here is the content... -->
  </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
img { float: left; }

.content:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
  width: 10em;    /* <-- Change the current width size */
}
```

Here is the **[JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/EJeVUrE/1/edit)**.

Comment: This is a nice solution, and well explained, thanks! I use `display: block;` and `overflow: hidden` on the `:before` instead of `table`, which does the same thing. The only problem is that this technique does not seem to work for text containers to the right of an image that has been floated left - but only in Firefox. Since the need to force a wrap only arises on small screens (i.e. mobiles) this is not a major issue; the Android browser, for example. does behave as expected.

Comment: Note that the need to force a wrap can arise on _any_ screen width -- it all depends on the size of the image.

Answer (score 4):

A better solution is to give every paragraph an invisible CSS pseudo-element with the desired minimum paragraph width. If there isn't enough space to fit this pseudo-element, then it will be pushed down underneath the image, taking the paragraph with it.

If the img is `flot: right`, add `clear: left` to the p:before.

And if the img is `float: left`, add `clear: right` to the p:before

```
p:before {
  content: "";
  width: 10em;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: left;   //use clear:right if img is float:left
}
```

Comment: This is a much nicer way of implementing [my "shim" solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18378962/61754). I just need to manage the vertical spacing, and target it better to apply only to the paragraph after the image.

Comment: @qwazix, Thank you for the feedback. I tried in firefox 41 and found this solution. Hope this helps. I have added **`clear: left;`** with **p:before**. I have edited this in my answer.

Comment: @jithin-b Not only does `clear: left` not fix the problem for me in Firefox, it breaks the functionallity in every other browser - I had to set the `:before` pseudoelement to `display: inline-block;` instead. It now works like a charm.

Comment: @j4k3 I think you may have given `float: left` to the image. Then you will have to use `clear: right` instead of clear: left for the `p:before`.

Comment: @j4k3 Yeah. `display: inline-block` will work. But it has a small problem with indentation and addition of `<br>` as @bennett-mcelwee mentioned. Otherwise it is  a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

I tried adding an extra element before the text. I think this would probably just about work. Something like this:

```
<style>
.shim { display: inline-block; height: 0; width: 12em; }
</style>

<img class="floated">
<div class="shim"></div><br>
If one examines Derridaist reading...
```

This is OK - if the flow column is narrow then the shim drops below the image and the text follows it. I have to add the `<br>` to stop the text being indented by 12 ems, which adds a line of vertical space. I guess I could reduce the line-height on the `<br>`but the whole thing might end up being a bit verbose.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method I found is to set the minimum width of the column by preventing the first few words from wrapping:

```
<style>
.chunk { white-space: nowrap; }
</style>

<p><span class="chunk">If one examines</span> Derridaist reading...
```

This works well, but:

- I have to manually edit the text each time I do this
- I can't precisely control the column width (in ems or pixels)